# How to properly and simply use callbacks in JNI NDK Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to have Java call a C function in Android and some caveats that I am met with is the documentation for callbacks in general seem very unclear and most answers on SO are just talking about theory and posting broken links with no actual code. So please post code in your answer.

I am trying to create a joystick in java and have it send input to the NDK to perform actions.

1. if I can just have Java call a C function and pass a int to it ,
   that would be good. but I think that wont work because C in running
   it's own main loop.
2. perhaps I need to use C to call a java
   function to get controller state and execute code from there.

I did manage to find some code [Here](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-jniCallback/app/src/main/cpp/hello-jnicallback.c) but it seems the code while it does compile by itself, but doesn't appear to work when moved to modern code .

How should I implement call backs in a Java C relationship on Android? It seems that from the code example above that it is C that is calling Java functions and these need to be used like  getters functions.

Here is some code that I have and I appear to be missing somethings because it is unclear to me how I should have these call backs performed. I will mark this code with function name and where is it located, if java or C++ (CPP) .

I think there are two ways that I would like this to work.

> My Javafunction that I want to call

```
public int Cat(){
        Log.e("JniHandler", "CAT WAS CALLED!!!");
        return 333;
    }
```

> Structure information CPP . Not sure if it is needed.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef struct tick_context {
    JavaVM  *javaVM;
    jclass   jniHelperClz;
    jobject  jniHelperObj;
    jclass   mainActivityClz;
    jobject  mainActivityObj;
    pthread_mutex_t  lock;
    int      done;
} TickContext;
TickContext g_ctx;
```

This section works. It looks that as soon as the JVM is launched, this will initialize.

> JNI_OnLoad  CPP

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env;
    memset(&g_ctx, 0, sizeof(g_ctx));

    SDL_Log(" DEBUG  -- JNI INIT!!!");
    g_ctx.javaVM = vm;
    if (vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR; // JNI version not supported.
    }


    jclass  clz = env->FindClass("org/foo/bar/mainactivity");
    g_ctx.jniHelperClz = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(clz); // hack

    jmethodID  jniHelperCtor = env->GetMethodID(g_ctx.jniHelperClz,"<init>", "()V");
    jobject    handler = env->NewObject(g_ctx.jniHelperClz, jniHelperCtor);
    g_ctx.jniHelperObj = env->NewGlobalRef(handler);
    //queryRuntimeInfo(env, g_ctx.jniHelperObj); // This when getting version returns null.
    
    g_ctx.done = 0;
    g_ctx.mainActivityObj = NULL;
    return  JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

> queryRuntimeInfo CPP

```
void queryRuntimeInfo(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    SDL_Log("DEBUG QUERYRUNTIME INTO");
    // Find out which OS we are running on. It does not matter for this app
    // just to demo how to call static functions.
    // Our java JniHelper class id and instance are initialized when this
    // shared lib got loaded, we just directly use them
    //    static function does not need instance, so we just need to feed
    //    class and method id to JNI
    jmethodID versionFunc = env->GetStaticMethodID(g_ctx.jniHelperClz, "getBuildVersion", "()Ljava/lang/String;"); // This returns null.
    if (!versionFunc) {
        SDL_Log("DEBUG versionFunc INTO");
        //LOGE("Failed to retrieve getBuildVersion() methodID @ line %d",__LINE__);
        return;
    }
    SDL_Log("DEBUG BUILD VERSION INTO");
    jstring buildVersion = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(g_ctx.jniHelperClz, versionFunc); // hack
    const char *version = env->GetStringUTFChars(buildVersion, NULL);

    if (!version) {
        SDL_Log("DEBUG buildVersion INTO");
        //LOGE("Unable to get version string @ line %d", __LINE__);
        return;
    }
    //LOGI("Android Version - %s", version);
    SDL_Log("DEBUG ANDROID VERSION %s", version);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(buildVersion, version);

    // we are called from JNI_OnLoad, so got to release LocalRef to avoid leaking
    env->DeleteLocalRef(buildVersion);

    // Query available memory size from a non-static public function
    // we need use an instance of JniHelper class to call JNI
    jmethodID memFunc = env->GetMethodID(g_ctx.jniHelperClz, "getRuntimeMemorySize", "()J");
    if (!memFunc) {
        //LOGE("Failed to retrieve getRuntimeMemorySize() methodID @ line %d",__LINE__);
        SDL_Log("DEBUG Failed to retrieve memory size");
        return;
    }
    jlong result = env->CallLongMethod(instance, memFunc);
    //LOGI("Runtime free memory size: %" PRId64, result);
    SDL_Log("DEBUG RUN TIME FREE MEMORY SIZE");
    (void)result;  // silence the compiler warning
}
```

> This function isn't ever called and I am not sure who is the caller. CPP

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL InvokeFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
    SDL_Log("JNI CALL START TICKET");
    pthread_t       threadInfo_;
    pthread_attr_t  threadAttr_;

    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr_);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr_, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    pthread_mutex_init(&g_ctx.lock, NULL);

    jclass clz = env->GetObjectClass(instance);
    g_ctx.mainActivityClz = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(clz); // hack
    g_ctx.mainActivityObj = env->NewGlobalRef(instance);

    int result  = pthread_create( &threadInfo_, &threadAttr_, UpdateTicks, &g_ctx);
    assert(result == 0);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttr_);

    (void)result;
}
```

> updateticks CPP // This code is never actually called.

```
void*  UpdateTicks(void* context) {

    SDL_Log("DEBUG -- UPDATE TICKS IS CALLED");
    TickContext *pctx = (TickContext*) context;
    JavaVM *javaVM = pctx->javaVM;
    JNIEnv *env;

    jint res = javaVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (res != JNI_OK) {
        res = javaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        if (JNI_OK != res) {
            //LOGE("Failed to AttachCurrentThread, ErrorCode = %d", res);

            SDL_Log("FAILED TO ATTACH THREAD");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    jmethodID statusId = env->GetMethodID(pctx->jniHelperClz, "updateStatus", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    //sendJavaMsg(env, pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, "TickerThread status: initializing...");

    // get mainActivity updateTimer function
    jmethodID timerId = env->GetMethodID(pctx->mainActivityClz, "updateTimer", "()V");

    struct timeval beginTime, curTime, usedTime, leftTime;
    const struct timeval kOneSecond = {
            (__kernel_time_t)1,
            (__kernel_suseconds_t) 0
    };

    //sendJavaMsg(env, pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, "TickerThread status: start ticking ...");
    while(1) {
        gettimeofday(&beginTime, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pctx->lock);
        int done = pctx->done;
        if (pctx->done) {
            pctx->done = 0;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pctx->lock);
        if (done) {
            break;
        }
        env->CallVoidMethod(pctx->mainActivityObj, timerId);

        gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
        timersub(&curTime, &beginTime, &usedTime);
        timersub(&kOneSecond, &usedTime, &leftTime);
        struct timespec sleepTime;
        sleepTime.tv_sec = leftTime.tv_sec;
        sleepTime.tv_nsec = leftTime.tv_usec * 1000;

        if (sleepTime.tv_sec <= 1) {
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        } else {
            //sendJavaMsg(env, pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, "TickerThread error: processing too long!");
        }
    }

    //sendJavaMsg(env, pctx->jniHelperObj, statusId, "TickerThread status: ticking stopped");
    javaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    return context;
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have an event loop in Java serving the Android event loop, and then a separate C thread running its own event loop. The quickest way to synchronize both is then to have a synchronized event queue that the Java code pushes events into (via JNI code), which the C event loop polls at each iteration.

Comment: Your `InvokeFunction` is called `Java_com_example_hellojnicallback_MainActivity_startTicks` in the sample. JNI names are special: this one is the implementation for the native `com.example.hellojnicallback.MainActivity#startTicks` method. In the sample it is called from [`onResume`](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-jniCallback/app/src/main/java/com/example/hellojnicallback/MainActivity.java#L36-L40)

Comment: I can try, but ultimately I need to confess I don't know proper procedure for this and I really am wanting to see some code and not just a "try xzy" .  I was curious about the naming convention , but no one has mentioned it.

Comment: The naming convention is in [section 2 of the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615). Giving you actual code is not possible until you have an idea of which architecture you want to pursue. Have you considered starting from an [Android Native Activity](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na)? That already has all the hooks in place for proxying Java events to a C event loop. That is *far* simpler than doing this complicated dance between Java and C.

Comment: I do have a native activity as I understand. I am not sure how to talk back and forth with Java and C

Comment: No, you don't. The official native activity has [no Java code](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/native-activity/app/src/main). It references a dummy activity that proxies everything to C, and you get the event queue mechanism I described for free.

Comment: To get an idea of what such an event queue entails, check the ScummVM Android port. [Java code pushing events](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/master/backends/platform/android/org/scummvm/scummvm/ScummVMEvents.java) to [JNI code](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/master/backends/platform/android/events.cpp), [C++ interface to pull events](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/master/backends/events/default/default-events.h)